# Change ListView highlight color

Tags: android

I am trying to change the highlight color of a ListView from the default orange/yellow color. I have tried setting `android:listSelector` but this causes rows tapped to be permanently selected. How can I either change the highlight color or prevent rows from staying selected please?

Answer (score 0):

you must use custom Listview for change Bg and BgHover 
for example :

Drawable folder:

**gradient_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <!-- Gradient Bg for listrow -->
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="#fdfdfd"
        android:endColor="#f8f8f8"
        android:startColor="#fdfdfd" />

</shape>
```

**gradient_bg_hover.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <!-- Gradient Bg for listrow -->
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="#fdfdfd"
        android:endColor="#f8f8f8"
        android:startColor="#f8f8f8" />

</shape>
```

**list_selector.xml**

```
<!-- Selector style for listrow -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
```

and Now use This list_selector.xml to Background of Listview